# Calculate intervals in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, intervals

I have two columns in a dataframe (a, and b). Note: I am only showing series here, but pretend that I am extracting those series from a dataframe with row index that I know (iloc).

I'm trying to extract some numbers from columns B, and calculate intervalls into a new series, and then, use it to make some operations with column a.

Intervals are as follow:

```
b[2]-b[1] 
b[3]-b[2] 
b[4]-b[3]
```

I have a code that works, but it is kind of, well not ugly, but a bit heavy. I have a feeling that there is a function that could do that.

Basically, I am creating an empty array, then iterating in the required range to calculate the interval. Is there a better way to proceed ?

```
a = pd.Series(data=[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], name='a')
b = pd.Series(data=[2,3,5,8,12,17], name='b')

ar = np.array([])

for i in range(1,4): 
    temp = b[i+1] - b[i]
    ar = np.append(ar, temp)

Result = a.iloc[2:5] * ar
```

I used numbers here, but my actual purpose it to do that with timestamp data. I need the timedelta between row[i+1] and row[i], and then, I need to do some operations. That's why I'm trying to calculate those intervals. I just neglected timestamps to make this easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and slice whatever range you want

```
b.diff()[2:5] * a[2:5]
```

---

As @sacul suggested in comments, can also slice just once and drop later `b.diff()[2:5].mul(a).dropna()`, even though that would imply generating lots of NaNs which, for big `df`s, might not be beneficial

Comment: nice! +1, and certainly more efficient than my answer (deleted). You could also do `b.diff()[2:5].mul(a).dropna()`, avoiding having to slice `a`. Not that it's necessarily better, but slightly different approach

Comment: That's it ? One single line of code ? And it works. I can use index calculated before. Thanks a lot. That will make my life much easier.